# Is it possible to change uploaded file?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I uploaded IFC file to bucket and opened it in viewer. I also extracted properties of clicked element (in my table) and now I need to add or delete some property. This part is OK but question is - how to save changed IFC file back? Is there option to save file loaded in viewer back?

Answer (score 1):

No. Basically, Forge is a read-only system. Certain components enable modification of certain file type, e.g., the [Forge Design Automation API](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/overview).